# Prove that two mappings are equal

Tags: functions

Let $f:A\to B$, $g:B\to C$ and $h:B\to C$ be mappings such that $g\circ f=h\circ f$ and $f$ is surjective.
Prove that $g=h$

I don't understand what is the difference if f is surjective or injective......

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f:\{0\}\to \{0,1\}$ defined by $f(0) = 0$, and $h:\{0,1\}\to \{0,1\}$ defined by $h(0) = 0,h(1) = 1$.  Now, consider $g:\{0,1\}\to \{0,1\}$ with $g(0) = 0$, and $g(1) = 0$.
We have that $g\circ f = h\circ f$ (verify this), but $g\neq h$ (as $g(1)\neq h(1)$).

Do you see how requiring $f$ to be injective makes the above not trick not work?

Answer (score 1):

The situation is the following: we have $3$ maps in the following configuration:
$$ A\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} B \stackrel{g,h}{\longrightarrow} C.$$
We know that $g\circ f=h\circ f$ as maps from $A$ to $C$, that is, for all $a\in A$
$$g(f(a))=h(f(a)).$$
We want to prove that $g=h$, and since these are maps $B\longrightarrow C$, this means that we want to prove that for all $b\in B$
$$g(b)=h(b).$$
Given that $f$ is surjective, we can write every $b\in B$ as $b=f(a)$ for some $a\in A$. So in this case $g=h$ follows from $g\circ f= h\circ f$. Do you see where this doesn't work if $f$ is not surjective? There will be some $b_0\in B$ which cannot be written as $b_0=f(a_0)$ and so the reasoning above will not work.

Answer (score 0):

- $f: A \rightarrow B$ is injective if for every element in the domain $A$ there exists a *unique* matching element  in $B$. In a more formal notation, we can write it as
  $$\forall x,y \in A, \ f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$$
- $f: A \rightarrow B$ is surjective if for every element in $B$ there exists at least one corresponding element in  $A$. Once again, in a more formal notation
  $$\forall b \in B, \exists a \in A \text{ such that } f(a) = b$$

So now, in your example we are told that $f$ is surjective. Looking at the definitions, note that this means that the $Im(f)= B$ (can you see why?), so both compositions are defined for any $x \in A$. We are also told that $g \circ f = h \circ f$, this means that $(g \circ f)(x) = (h \circ f)(x)\ \forall x \in A$. Can you take it from here?